# WordPress Plugin works other than Firefox

Tags: firefox, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I am using the "MediaElement.js - HTML5 Audio and Video" plugin on a WordPress site and it works great, other than the fact that I can't get it to work in Firefox.

I am only using it for audio clips and I am using mp3 files.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Maybe add some things to your question like what you've tried, which version of firefox/wordpress you're using, etc. Welcome to stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following codes to the.htaccess file and see if it works.

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3